# VB.net Datagridview count items that have 2 different values

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview with 4 columns (Status, Date, ID, Time) I am trying to count how many items based on ID that have 2 different statuses on them from previous and current day.  I am struggling to get the correct query.

I am new to Datagridview and queries.
I have tried the below but cannot figure it out.

```
Dim distinctGODSCO() As String = (From row As DataGridViewRow 
     In DataGridView3.Rows.Cast(OfDataGridViewRow)() 
     Where row.Cells(3).Value In 
     (Select row.Cells(3).Value From DataGridView3.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() 
      Where row.Cells(0).Value = "GOD" And 
            row.Cells(1).Value >= GODDay())) And 
             row.Cells(0).Value = "SCO") 
             Select CStr(row.Cells(2).Value)).Distinct.ToArray
```

I have the one below that just looks for a single status and works right but i cannot seem to get the above to work.

```
Dim distinctGOD() As String = (From row As DataGridViewRow In  
    DataGridView3.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
    Where Not row.IsNewRow And 
        row.Cells(0).Value = "GOD" And 
        row.Cells(3).Value > WorkingDay & " 00:01" And  
        row.Cells(3).Value < WorkingDay & " " & NR1Time And  
        row.Cells(0).Value IsNot DBNull.Value
            Select CStr(row.Cells(2).Value)).Distinct.ToArray
```

Comment: Whatever `Cell(0)` is, its value cannot be both "GOD" and "SCO" at the same time, which is what you are currently searching for

Comment: Hi.  Cell 0 is the status and can either be SCO or GOD + other statuses.  Cell 2 is the unique ID.  There will be multiple records and one with the ID of 004 may have a status of  GOD and record 007 will have the same ID but a status of SCO.   What i am trying to find is when the ID has a status of GOD or SCO in different records.  The data is Scans of freight with GOD meaning Goods On Dock and SCO meaning Scanned Out.  So i need to find records that will have had GOD and then later SCO and the ID is the unique freight ID.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Right, so you should be filtering using OR instead of AND as the status it's either or not both